# check enable of logger level vs don't check in SLF4J\Logback

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I using `SLF4J` and `Logback` for logging infrastructure at my application.
I using `Logger.isDebugEnable()` method before any log, for sample:

```
if(logger.isDebugEnable())
    logger.debug('process transaction....')
```

goal of above code is : don't construct string `process transaction....` in heap when log level is not `Debug`.

My question is:
Is there benefit between my code style or direct `logger.debug('process transaction....')` without check enable log level?

Answer (score 3):

This is a legacy from the log4j project.  slf4j has introduced the {} construction which allow you to use:

```
logger.debug("{}: {}", "MyClass", "Message to show to user");
```

where the logger backend first checks for "is...Enabled()" and *then* constructs the logger string.

As the backend checks itself you do not need to, and the if clause can be removed leaving only the logger statement itself.

Comment: I understand your means of parameterized log string but I means is not it, In java when a method call occurred ,input parameter construct and in my code `process transaction....` string construct and then `SLF4J` check log level enable.

Comment: Rewrite your current logstatement to use {} and pass arguments in accordingly.

Comment: if it is cheap to construct your string to log then there is no difference.  This optimization change is only relevant if you would otherwise construct a lot of strings that never actually made it to the logfile.